# Thread not working in java android

Tags: java, android

I am a brand new geek into android and java. So, please bear with me. So, I have the following piece of code (only an extract) : -

```
Thread timer=new Thread();
try{
    timer.sleep(2000);
}
catch(InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();                    
}
finally{
Intent openstartingpoint=new Intent("android.intent.action.START");
startActivity(openstartingpoint);
}
```

The error which I am receiving in eclipse is : - `The method sleep() should be accessed in a static way`
The application also works. But, the text of the current activity is not shown. I only get a blank screen for 2 seconds.

**== EDIT ==**

But, everything works good with this code. Can anyone tell me the reason why?

```
Thread timer=new Thread(){
public void run(){
    try{
    sleep(5000);
    }
catch(InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();                    
    }
    finally{
    Intent openstartingpoint=new Intent("android.intent.action.START");
    startActivity(openstartingpoint);
    }
}
};
    timer.start();
```

Comment: Before learning android I strongly recommend you to have solid knowledge of Java, you will never regret it, and if you are thinking on making a career out of it will prevent you from a lot of headaches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only a warning you are getting, because sleep is a static method, it should be called as,

`Thread.sleep(200);`

This means it will put current thread on sleep for 200 milliseconds, so even if you are calling it using an object, still it will put current thread (not timer) on sleep.

In case one :

say you are in main thread, and call

`timer.sleep(200);`

it will put main thread(as I said **current thread**, timer is not started, current thread is **main**) on sleep.

but in case two : the new thread(timer), which you are creating will be put on sleep. That's the difference.

[you can refer to java docs for better understanding.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)

Comment: What do you mean by a static method?

Comment: if syntax is considered - it means method declared with static keyword like : public static void main(String str[]). Conceptually - it means the method will not be object specific. It should be called with class name.

Answer (score 2):

In first one you didn't call sleep() method in right context. Like people before me said that is static method in Thread class, and if you want to stop the thread for some time it must be called in run method.
Also be careful where you start your thread and if it changes GUI since it will cause exception.

Answer (score 2):

Call the method as Thread.sleep(2000);

sleep is a static method of class Thread so it can be accessed using classname directly.

In second code mentioned below, you are not getting an error because you are creating an anonymous class which is calling sleep method directly using the Thread class in a static way.

```
    Thread timer=new Thread()
    {
      public void run(){
         try
            {
              sleep(5000);
            }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
       {
        e.printStackTrace();                    
       }
        finally
        {
        Intent openstartingpoint=new Intent("android.intent.action.START");
        startActivity(openstartingpoint);
        }
      }
    };
        timer.start();
```